# Let $X$ ~ Geometric with $p=\frac{1} {4}$ and $Y$ ~ Uniform on $(1,2,3,4)$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given X and Y are independent, I need to find $VAR(2X + 2Y)$.
Does independence mean that $VAR(2X + 2Y) = VAR(2X) + VAR(2Y)$? If so, then $VAR(X)=\dfrac{1-p} {p^2} = \dfrac{\dfrac {3} {4}} {\dfrac{1} {16}}=12$. And $VAR(Y)= \dfrac {1} {4}(1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +4^2)-[\dfrac{1} {4}(1+2+3+4)]^2=\dfrac{5} {4}.$ Then $VAR(2X+2Y)=2VAR(X)+2VAR(Y)=24+10/2=\dfrac{53} {2}$?

Did I do this right or am I off somehow?
Thanks!

Comment: One mistake: in general, $Var(cX)=c^2 \cdot Var(X)$.

Comment: Oh that's right! Then that is $4VAR(X)+4VAR(Y)$? That means the answer is 53.

Answer (score 1):

$$Var(2X+2Y) =Var(2(X+Y)) = 4Var(X+Y) = 4[Var(X) + Var(Y)]$$

Or:

If X and Y are independent, then 2X and 2Y are independent.

$$Var(2X+2Y)=Var(2X)+Var(2Y)=4Var(X)+4Var(Y)$$

Assuming your $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$ are correct, we have $Var(2X+2Y)=53.$